# Prove-idea for writing an odd prime number as a difference of two square-numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

You can generate an odd natural number $n$ by subtracting two square-numbers:

$$n = 2k + 1 \qquad k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \\
\Leftrightarrow n = k^2 + 2k + 1 - k^2 = (k+1)^2 - k^2 $$

Now is it sufficient to say that every odd primenumber can be generated *inimitably* 
with

$n = (k+1)^2 - k^2$

since

$n = 2k + 1$ is a linear function and a bijection?

[image]

Comment: No.  $9=3^2-0^2=5^2-4^2$.  If you want non-zero squares then $21=5^2-2^2=11^2-10^2$.

Comment: More broadly, your squares are (obviously) consecutive but the difference of any two squares of different parities is odd.

Comment: "$n = 2k+1$ is a linear function and a _bijection_" Be careful here. Bijectivity only makes sense if you have defined your domain and codomain. As a function from the real numbers to the real numbers, sure, it's a bijection. As a function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers (or the integers to the integers), it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you were asking -- technically, yes, the formula $n = 2k+1$ gives a bijection between odd natural numbers and natural numbers, so you could take any natural number $k$, compute $(k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1$, and check if $2k+1$ is prime; if it is, you will not generate the same prime from a different $k$.

However, I'm not sure what you've gained by doing this. It's equivalent to taking a list of odd natural numbers $1,3,5,7,9,\dots$, and checking each number on the list to see if it's prime.

Comment: I wanted to show that you can use this linear function to generate odd primes in a unique way. But user lulu proofed me wrong. :)

Comment: @user1511417 I don't think lulu proved you wrong -- you were considering $(k+1)^2 - k^2$, while lulu was considering $(k+m)^2-k^2$. You were answering different questions.

Comment: The question is whether *this* bijection is enough to proof, that there is only one $k$ for each single primenumber.

Comment: @user1511417 The answer is yes. Each prime number comes from a unique odd number (itself), and each odd number comes from a unique natural number $k$ via the $n = 2k+1$ relation.